# Авторское тире перед последним однородным членом

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, однородные-члены, авторская-пунктуация

> У каждого московского студента наступает момент, когда ходить по «Шоколадницам», потягивать мохито в барах на Тверской, по субботам отвисать в клубе Icon, а на майские гонять с друзьями в Испанию — и делать всё это на родительское бабло уже совесть не позволяет.

Чтобы логически отделить последний однородный член, допустимо ли поставить авторское тире?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что здесь надо применить вставную конструкцию:

У каждого московского студента наступает момент, когда ходить по «Шоколадницам», потягивать мохито в барах на Тверской, по субботам отвисать в клубе Icon, а на майские гонять с друзьями в Испанию **— и делать всё это на родительское бабло —** уже совесть не позволяет.

Весь ряд сложно считать единой конструкцией, так как союзы А и И некорректно сочетаются друг с другом внутри одно ряда.

Comment: Почему некорректно? Наверное, не то чтобы некорректно, а просто тогда союз «и» соединяет лишь два последних члена после союза «а»: _А, Б, В, а Г и Д_.

Comment: Союз А связывает придаточные 3 и 4, придаточное  5 имеет обобщенное (но отнюдь не однородное)  значение по отношению к четыре предыдущим - не очень-то однородная семантика просматриваются внутри этого ряда.

Comment: Придаточные? Разве это не однородные дополнения, выраженные инфинитивами?

Comment: Если абстрагироваться от смысла 5-го члена, то в общем случае он будет однородным только с 4-м членом из-за союза «а». Верно?

Comment: Совесть не позволяет ходить, потягивать и т.д.  Это составное глагольное сказуемое с модальной связкой (значение волеизъявления), и мы имеем однородный РЯД сказуемых с бессоюзной и союзной связью. Они однородны грамматически, а с точки зрения семантики однородны не полностью (5-й член имеет  значение обобщения). Но НЕ ЭТО даже важно. Основная проблема в том, что  3-й и 4-й член связаны союзом А, из-за чего союз И уже не  может замыкать весь ряд.

Comment: Пример однородного ряда: У каждого московского студента наступает момент, когда ходить по «Шоколадницам», потягивать мохито в барах на Тверской, по субботам отвисать в клубе Icon,  на майские праздники гонять с друзьями в Испанию  и делать всё это на родительское бабло уже совесть не позволяет. Здесь весь ряд можно считать условно однородным, но поставить одно авторское тире всё равно нельзя, так как за однородным рядом предложение продолжается (одну паузу уже не сделаешь). Поэтому только вставка.

Comment: Я не спорю — на основной вопрос вы ответили. Просто попутно у меня возник другой вопрос: "У каждого московского студента наступает момент, когда ходить по «Шоколадницам», потягивать мохито в барах на Тверской, по субботам отвисать в клубе Icon, а на майские гонять с друзьями в Испанию и делать это на родительское бабло уже совесть не позволяет" (без "всё") — в таком случае 5-ый член будет однородным только с 4-м членом и конструкция будет грамматически правильной?

Comment: А по-моему, "позволяет" здесь полноценный знаменательный глагол, а не связка: "Совесть не позволяет студенту ходить, потягивать…" Вы не согласны?